# cakephp saveMany() with foreach loop

Tags: arrays, cakephp, csv

Just a fairly easy question that cant seem to work for me.

is it possible to use cakePHP's saveMany() to save an array of arrays.
case example:
if you have a csv file with many columns and rows.in my case calling saveMany inside a foreach loop only saves the first row of the csv file and stops.

i thougth it should do save row after row but seems i was wrong.
Is there an easier way to do this still in cakephp?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `saveMany()` to save multiple of the same model at one time.  You have to format the data carefully, or else it won't work:

```
$data = array(
   0 => array(
     'Model' => array(
        'field1' => 1,
        'field2' => 2,
     ),
   ),
   1 => array(
     'Model' => array(
        'field1' => 1,
        'field2' => 2,
     ),
   ),
);
```

Or you can leave out the 'Model' like so:

```
$data = array(
   0 => array(
      'field1' => 1,
      'field2' => 2,
   ),
   1 => array(
      'field1' => 1,
      'field2' => 2,
   ),
);
```

See the cookbook about SaveMany:  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array

Comment: what if you have  many $data in that format and need to save them one after the other